# Inheritance of overloaded methods in Java and C++ differ in what fundamental way?

Tags: java, c++, overloading

I am studying for my final exam in my comparative languages course and the professor gave us an old exam to get a feel for the real deal. One question I don't understand is this:

"The inheritance of overloaded methods in Java and C++ differ in a fundamental way. Clearly show the difference in the two approaches taken and argue why Java's design decision is preferable."

The only idea I have about this question is a memory I have about Java operator overloading and how you can't do that, but in C++ you can.

Comment: I'd say that any question that *presupposes* that "Java's design decision is preferable" is academically fraudulent, and ethically repulsive. (In response to the question, I think it's to do with `virtual` functions.)

Comment: @KerrekSB It says "argue" - does that mean the people writing the debate club notes are academically fraudulent and ethically repulsive as well? ;) In all seriousness though, many profs love to have more than one test, so what makes you think that the half of the class didn't have to argue exactly the other way around? I certainly could find enough talk points for both sides of the argument easily..

Comment: @Voo: It says "argue why", not "argue whether". I think that's a pretty big difference! :-) It'd be awesome if there were truly two camps, but somehow I seriously doubt it that any contemporary CS class would be run that way :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB Well if it said "whether" it wouldn't be much of two different camps here - that's just as the same as in the debate club: You get a position and have to defend it - certainly fits with my conflicting nature ;) Obviously the prof could be everything you said and more, but in dubio pro reo ;-) As an anecdote I once had a compiler exam where one half of the class had to argue in favor of LALR and the other half for LR parsers.

Comment: @Voo: Ah, I understand. You really *want* someone to defend a given position. Yeah, I guess that could be fun. I should hope that the question clarifies that, though, and does not suggest that that position is in fact correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask the lecturer for an example inheritance hierarchy that demonstrates the "inheritance of overloaded methods." I would take it to mean something like the following in C++:

```
struct A1 { };
struct A2 { };

struct B1 {
    virtual void f(A1*) = 0;
};

struct B2 {
    virtual void f(A2*) = 0;
};

struct D : B1, B2 { };

void f(D& d)
{
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    d.f(&a1);
    d.f(&a2);
}
```

And the following in Java (my Java is a little rough so I hope I have gotten it about right):

```
class M {
    class A1 { };
    class A2 { };

    interface B1 {
        void f(A1 a1);
    };
    interface B2 {
        void f(A2 a2);
    };

    abstract class D implements B1, B2 {
    }; 

    void f(D d)
    {
        A1 a1 = new A1();
        A2 a2 = new A2();
        d.f(a1);
        d.f(a2);
    }
};
```

Note that the difference here is that the C++ code will not compile because f() is ambiguous. Whereas the Java code will compile. If this is what they are talking about, you could argue that Java is doing what the programmer would expect whereas C++ is likely to surprise the programmer. **One important thing I learned at Uni is that passing Uni courses in programming sometimes means answering questions the way the assessor expects you to first and correctly second.**

Comment: +1: Agree, that at Uni giving the expected answer is more important than trying to be correct. ;)

Answer (score 3):

seems that most answers here talk about inheritance and method "Overriding" in C++/Java.

However, there is a keyword in the question makes me think that he is in fact asking for another thing:  "The inheritance of **overloaded** methods"

There is one fundamental difference if I remember correctly, about Inheritance + Method overloading:

In C++, if you overloaded a method in child class which is declared in parent class, it will cause method shadowing.  This may cause some surprisings in your design if you are not aware of it. If I remember correctly, if parent class have 2 overloading methods, and in child class, you override one of it, it will still cause shadowing.

However everything is fine in Java.

If this is really what is asking, then honestly Java's way is preferrable, because method overloading shouldn't interfere the method inheritance and overriding.  And such shadowing causes many design problem, like you will not be able to access parent class method directly in the overloading+inheritance+shadowing scenario.

Answer (score -1):

> The inheritance of overloaded methods in Java and C++ differ in a
>   fundamental way.

1. In Java, when base `class` method is overridden by derived `class`,
   they both are related in polymorphic way by default. In C++ you have
   to make `base` method as `virtual`
2. In Java you can stop the method overriding by making it `final`. In
   current C++, that is not available

> argue why Java's design decision is preferable.

That's controversial. Java enforces single way of design, which helps programmers understand the code better/faster. Also reduces confusion and exploitation of language features.

C++ supports multi paradigm and **pay per use** terminology, which provides flexibility, but also making it an expert oriented language.

Comment: I'd say 'current' c++ is c++11 since the standard is finalized now, and `final` is available in c++11.

Comment: @bames53, agreed. It's like a habit for me to refer C++03 as current one. Need to change that.

Comment: -1. Not relevant. Question is about overloading, not overriding.

Comment: @EJP, OP has mistakenly used thw "overloading" term. "Overloading of inherited method" is essentially "overriding" only.

Comment: @iammilind That's not so. See Bowie Owens' answer.